# Conditional WHERE statement SQL

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get a conditional WHERE statement but I'm not sure how to do this without using CASE WHEN.

```
SELECT * FROM
  `...`
WHERE (CASE WHEN product <> 'core news' THEN type <> 'video')
ORDER BY product, metric, type
```

Comment: 1) tag  the database that you are using  as well 2) provide sample data and desired output 3) why not using case stataments?

Comment: What's wrong with a `CASE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly I believe you want

```
SELECT * FROM
  `...`
WHERE product = 'core news' OR (product <> 'core news' AND type <> 'video')
ORDER BY product, metric, type
```

Comment: Yes thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable
WHERE 
(
     (product <> 'core news' AND type <> 'video') 
  OR (product = 'core news') 
) 
ORDER BY product, metric, type
```